# Change width/height of ellipse to always be circular, independent of viewing angle

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I have the following shader graph attached to a quad that draws two circles at some position.

[image: Shader Graph]

Naturally, when viewed at an angle, the circles appear to be ellipses.

[image: angled view]

I'd like to know how to adjust the width/height parameters of the ellipse nodes to always appear as circles, roughly like this:

[image: adjusted ellipse width to appear circular]

(Note that the green sphere in this picture is still a bit smaller because it is further away, this is correct.)